# Box character doesn't display properly in Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, unicode, cpp

I was just writing a C++] program that uses the box characters to display information. 
I ran the program on macOS and used the terminal app and it worked fine.

When I switched to [Debian Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) using the same code and recompiling it,
I only then encountered this problem! 
I've searched online for answers,
but I have found none related to this problem. 
I've tested this with both [LXTerminal](https://github.com/lxde/lxterminal) and [URXVT](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvt.1).

Here is my minimal reproducible example of this problem:

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

int ch;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    initscr();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    nodelay(stdscr, true);
    curs_set(0);
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, -1);

    clear();
    refresh();

    while ((ch = getch()) != 'q' && ch != 'Q') {

        attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));

        mvprintw(0,0,"┏━┓");
        mvprintw(1,0,"┗━┛");

    }

    refresh();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this demo with this command below:

```
g++ -g -c -o main.o test.cpp && g++ -g -o test main.o -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -lncurses
```

or

```
LDLIBS=-lncurses make test
```

Instead of displaying

```
┏━┓
┗━┛
```

it displays this:

```
M-b~T~OM-b~T~AM-b~T~S
M-b~T~WM-b~T~AM-b~T~[
```

#### Actual screen images

Normal (desired) display on macOS:

[image: Normal (desired) display on macOS]

Abnormal display on Linux:

[image: Abnormal display on Linux]

Comment: I think it doesn't matter what terminal emulator you use but if it makes you happy I tried it with LXTerminal and URXVT. @terdon

Comment: And did you recompile? How did you compile? Please [edit] your question and add these details. And yes, it absolutely matters which terminal you use since you are using non-ASCII characters so you need a terminal that supports them. lxterminal does though, and your program works fine with lxterminal, so it's going to be something about how you compiled it. So please [edit] your question and tell us whether you compiled on Linux and, if so, how.

Comment: Odd. I ran the exact same thing and tested with lxterminal and it worked fine. If you run `echo $TERM`, that returns `xterm-256color`, right?

Comment: Wait, are you redirecting to a file or is that the direct output printed to the terminal?

Comment: Yes when I run `echo $TERM `, it returns `xterm-256color `. I am using printw() to display the box so its direct output to the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that box character didn't display properly in a Linux terminal. The solution is that you need to compile the code differently.

If you are using `printw` or some other text displaying method that uses ncurses as a library, then this will apply to you. 
This is OS dependent, so if you are on macOS you would use the `-lncurses` flag
when compiling (also according to @terdon this also applies to [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux),
but I haven't tested that),
and if you are using Linux
(I've tested it only for Debian) you need to use the `-lncursesw` flag.

If you want to automatically make your code cross-compatible for this issue,
put this in your makefile.

```
ifneq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
        NCURSES += -lncursesw
    endif
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
        NCURSES += -lncurses
    endif
endif
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that you're using literal characters `┌`, `─`, `┐`, `└`, `─`, `┘` instead of using the `ncurses`-independent symbols. You should use the `ACS_??CORNER` (for `U`pper/`L`ower and `L`eft/`R`ight) and `ACS_HLINE` symbolic names and let `ncurses` work out how to represent those on your terminal.

Modifying your code from this,

```
mvprintw(0,0,"┏━┓");
mvprintw(1,0,"┗━┛");
```

to this,

```
move(0,0); addch(ACS_ULCORNER); addch(ACS_HLINE); addch(ACS_URCORNER);
move(1,0); addch(ACS_LLCORNER); addch(ACS_HLINE); addch(ACS_LRCORNER);
```

should ensure that the code works portably. I also changed the end of your `main()` procedure from a plain `return 0` to the following, so that the terminal will be correctly reset when the program ends:

```
endwin();
exit(0);
```

Compile `test.cpp` and execute with,

```
LDLIBS=-lncurses make test && ./test
```

Useful references, in no particular order:

- [NCURSES Extended Characters Quick Reference Charts and Screen Layout Chart](http://www.melvilletheatre.com/articles/ncurses-extended-characters/index.html)
- [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html)
- [add a character (with attributes) to a curses window, then advance the cursor](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_addch.3.asp)

Comment: Any idea why the OP's code did work for me on Arch? I tested with the exact same code, same compilation command, and terminal emulators `ternminator`, `gnome-terminal`, `lxterminal`, `xterm`, all fine. I realize you can't know exactly why, you don't have access to my system, but what kind of thing would this depend on?

Comment: [@roaima I like your answer, it's correct but is there a simpler way to display the characters with printw? Printing out one character at a time seams inefficient. I'm trying to make a terminal game and it uses the characters quite allot. Also the characters that are printed from your code look thinner. Sorry if I sound picky.]
[@terdon I find It very odd how the characters display properly for `lxterminal` on your OS but not mine? Are you using the default setting that `lxterminal` comes with, no customisation. Maybe it's OS dependent, idk?]

Comment: @terdon: Arch only has ncurses 6.x, which has merged libncursesw into libncurses (or rather the opposite – /lib/libncurses.so is a linker script that redirects to "-lncursesw") so the wide-character support is always present, unlike in ncurses 5.x which appears to still be the default on Debian and which had separate wide and non-wide variants of the library, as the post by Thomas Dickey mentions.

Comment: It is highly unlikely to be a terminal emulator issue; terminal emulators that receive UTF-8 data but don't know to interpret it as such would simply show all three bytes as if they were ISO 8859 characters (with the initial byte usually showing up as `â` `â` or similar) – whereas the `M-` (Ctrl-) notation for 8-bit characters almost always comes from the non-wide ncurses being used, i.e. the original UTF-8 data doesn't even reach the terminal.

Comment: @user1686 I don't think it's the terminal emulator either. At best it's ncurses misunderstanding what to do with an extended unicode character, but I wanted a non-UTF8 environment in which to test

Comment: @sherbitfish I can't see a way to get the thicker box lines. I tried `attron(A_BOLD)` but on my terminal that made no difference

Comment: @user1686 I found a command that allows you to see the version of ncurses from one of Thomas Dicky post.`/usr/bin/tic -V` When I ran the command on MacOS it returned `ncurses 5.7.20081102`, and then on Debian/Raspberry Pi OS `ncurses 6.2.20201114`.

Comment: I worked out the solution to the problem. If you are interested read my answer.

Comment: @terdon, "_Any idea why the OP's code did work for me on Arch?_" - after an hour digging around, the answer's (still) no, sorry! I think [Thomas Dickey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/738901/100397) probably explains it better, although mine provides a solution

Answer (score 10):

On MacOS, the `-lncurses` links to the wide-character configuration of ncurses, which normally is provided by `-lncursesw`.  The `setlocale` call gives different results in those (normal versus wide characters), and the literal string for the box-characters (which is UTF-8) comes out differently.

Further reading:

- [*Curses library doesn't support wide char on OS X high sierra*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042203/curses-library-doesnt-support-wide-char-on-os-x-high-sierra/48043276#48043276), for my explanation
- [*Alternate Configurations*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ALTERNATE-CONFIGURATIONS) in the ncurses manual
- [*keyname*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name), which expands on *unctrl* and *addch*, noting

> - Values  above 128 are either meta characters (if the screen has not
>   been initialized, or if meta(3x) has been called with a TRUE parameter),  shown  in the ***M-X*** notation, or are displayed as themselves. In the latter case, the values may not be printable;  this  follows the X/Open specification.

The underlying issue is that the UTF-8 encoding for the box characters uses byte-codes above 128, and without the locale support used in the wide-character library, you'll get just that—no reassembly of the bytes into a wide-character.

Some other platforms also present `-lncurses` as an alias for `-lncursesw`, e.g., (noting a comment), Arch Linux which has this in `/usr/lib/ncurses.so`:

```
INPUT(-lncursesw)
```

Another comment asked about "thick lines".  There are a few points here:

- In my answer [*Double line box_drawing characters in terminal*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89780/double-line-box-drawing-characters-in-terminal/276338#276338), I mentioned that ncurses provides symbols for convenience in using the Unicode *thick* and *double* lines.
- Those have been in ncurses since [October 2009](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2009-10/msg00015.html):

> I only implemented WACS_xxx symbols for thick/double-lines for the usual
> reasons: it's experimental, and only useful with Unicode.

- The symbols are documented in the [`wadd_wch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) manual page.
- The feature is not available for MacOS's bundled ncurses, since that (ncurses 5.7) is about a year older than the change in ncurses.
- It will not work for the Linux console terminal (because that relies upon a font with only 512 glyphs).
- The actual *appearance* of thick/double lines is unspecified (it depends on the fonts).